# Effect of git checkout -b branchname vs git checkout branchname

Tags: git

I accidentally entered

```
git checkout -b develop
```

instead of

```
git checkout develop
```

Even though the develop branch already existed, it said it had been created.

Has that affected the code in the `develop` branch? I can't find any clear documentation on this.

Comment: You can try run `gitk --all`, to visually inspect what happened

Comment: If you were in the develop branch, I guess it would have taken a branch off that branch called develop? If you weren't in the develop branch, this shouldn't have happened unless you were in the wrong repository. Like Steve Penny suggested visual inspection will help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has that affected the code in the **develop** branch? I can't find any
> clear documentation on this.

Nope. Your `develop` branch is in a netherworld where your next choices will determine what might happen.

Here is the deal as I understand it: If you have already checked out `develop` prior, you would not be able to run this command:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

The response would be—and I just tested on my local machine to confirm—would be:

```
fatal: A branch named 'develop' already exists.
```

So what happened in your case when `git checkout -b develop` was run? Easy. You had not checked out `develop` previously.  So git was doing what it was told to do by that command: create a *local* branch named `develop`.

Now if you did something there and then pushed it to origin. Well, that would be a mess if you forced the situation.  Read on.

And to further clarify things, if you do a straight clone of a git repository without doing anything else and then you ran the following command in that repository directory you would see something like this if you run `git branch -a`:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Note the `*` master and the `remote/origin/` items following that. That is the key to understanding what you did and why it was able to happen. You see, until you actually checkout `develop` it simply exists as a remote *reference* (key point) in your local clone. But when you do a `git checkout develop` the structure would be like this if you run `git branch -a` afterwards:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Note that now you have the `*` connected to `develop` which means that is the currently checked out branch.

The key to understanding git is there are local *copies* and there are remote *references*. Anything past `master` won’t be checked out until the moment you actually check it out.

And past that, let’s say you did a `git checkout -b develop` from `master` without a local `develop` in place. Okay, great! Now do some work on your code and then do a `git pull`.  You would most likely get this message:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> develop
```

Which basically means your local `develop` is not connected to a remote `develop` so git needs help clarifying things. Something like this should clue you into something being amiss.

**BUT WAIT!** You are not 100% safe yet. This is where things might get scary if you do a `git push origin develop`. If you indeed have a branch named `develop` on the remote you will most likely overwrite it with this new branch. So avoid that if you can.  But in some cases this might be the response:

```
To git@github.com:CoolCoderDude4Life/The-Best-Repo.git
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:CoolCoderDude4Life/The-Best-Repo.git
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

You see at this point you do get another warning that something is off. But at the same time you can simply read this in haste and follow the directions and *BOOM* work is somehow lost.

Might be a longer answer than what you are looking for. But a decent teachable moment on how a version control system can be a safety net, but safety nets can break. So good coding habits need to be a part of a workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Well the big question is if the branch existed locally or remote.

My guess is that it did not exists locally because you should get an error

> fatal: A branch named 'develop' already exists.

if it did

If indeed locally there is no need to worry as what you did is created a new local branch from the branch that was active at that moment (i guess master)

As long as you don't push (what i don't think git will allow) you can just remove your local branch without problems.

But i always like to be safe so whenever i do something strange in git and want to undo it i make a copy of my local repo "just in case".

Answer (score 1):

> Has that affected the code in the develop branch?

No, especially if that branch was in `remotes/origin` namespace (`origin/develop`).
You can check that with a:

```
git branch -avvv
```

You can reset it to the right origin with:

```
git checkout -B develop origin/develop
```